# How to iterate array in object using variable as the object property name? - TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to iterate array in object using variable as the object property name but it just not works..
Is there a way to do it?

This is my code:

```
interface Task {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}

interface AgendaState {
    todayTasks: Task[];
    nextTasks: Task[];
}

const state: AgendaState = {
    todayTasks: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Task Title' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Task Title 2' },
    ],
    nextTasks: [
        { id: 3, title: 'Task Title 3' },
        { id: 4, title: 'Task Title 4' },
    ]
};

const theFrames = {
    TODAY: 'todayTasks',
    NEXT: 'nextTasks'
};

const typeFrame = theFrames.TODAY;


const task: Task = { id: 1, title: 'Replace Task Title' }
const replacedTaskList = state[typeFrame].map(t => t.id === task.id ? task : t);
// OR
// const filteredTaskList = state[typeFrame].filter(t => t.id !== task.id);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it just not works"? This is not a way to frame a question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

The problem is typescript is calculating `theFrames` type as `{TODAY:  string; NEXT: string; }`, but `string` can't be used as key of `state`.

Easiest way to fix it:

```js
interface Task {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface AgendaState {
  todayTasks: Task[];
  nextTasks: Task[];
}

const state: AgendaState = {
  todayTasks: [
    { id: 1, title: 'Task Title' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Task Title 2' },
  ],
  nextTasks: [
    { id: 3, title: 'Task Title 3' },
    { id: 4, title: 'Task Title 4' },
  ]
}

const theFrames = {
  TODAY ='todayTasks',
  NEXT = 'nextTasks',
} as const

const task: Task = {id: 1, title: 'Replace Task Title'};

const replacedTaskList = state[Frames.TODAY].map(t => t.id === task.id ? task : t);
const filteredTaskList = state[Frames.TODAY].filter(t => t.id !== task.id);
```

Another way:

```js
interface Task {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

enum Frames {
  TODAY = 'todayTasks',
  NEXT = 'nextTasks',
}

type AgendaState = Record<Frames, Task[]>;

const state: AgendaState = {
  [Frames.TODAY]: [
    { id: 1, title: 'Task Title' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Task Title 2' },
  ],
  [Frames.NEXT]: [
    { id: 3, title: 'Task Title 3' },
    { id: 4, title: 'Task Title 4' },
  ]
}

const task: Task = {id: 1, title: 'Replace Task Title'};

const replacedTaskList = state[Frames.TODAY].map(t => t.id === task.id ? task : t);
const filteredTaskList = state[Frames.TODAY].filter(t => t.id !== task.id);
```

Comment: It's still not type safe though

Comment: If you want to add something, write more...? @geoffrey

Comment: What would happen if you added a value in your enum that is not in `state`?

Comment: Yep! Referencing `Frames` directly in `state`'s properties creates an unnecessary indirection for the reader so I would rollback that change but it's definitely an improvement

Comment: The problem of directly accessing `state['wrongProp']` still remains, but it is more of a design problem than a typing issue.